# Implementation of a market that matches bids to offers

Tags: java, performance, tree, memory-management, binary-search

This is my task:

Each line in the file can be one of the following:

Updates to the limit order book in the following format:

```
u,<price>,<size>,bid - set bid size at <price> to <size>
u,<price>,<size>,ask - set ask size at <price> to <size>
```

Queries in the following format:

```
q,best_bid - print best bid price and size
q,best_ask - print best ask price and size
q,size,<price> - print size at specified price (bid, ask or spread).
```

And market orders in the following format:

```
o,buy,<size> - removes <size> shares out of asks, most cheap ones.
o,sell,<size> - removes <size> shares out of bids, most expensive ones
```

In case of a buy order this is similar to going to a market (assuming that you want to buy  similar items there, and that all instances have identical quality, so price is the only factor) - you buy  units at the cheapest price available.

Queries, market orders, and limit order book updates are in arbitrary sequence. Each line in the file is either one of the three and ends with a UNIX newline character - \n.

Input values range:
Price - 1...109
Size - 0...108

Example of input file:

```
u,9,1,bid
u,11,5,ask
q,best_bid
u,10,2,bid
q,best_bid
o,sell,1
q,size,10
u,9,0,bid
u,11,0,ask
```

Output file
Example of output file (for this input file):

```
9,1
10,2
1
```

My current solution for this problem :

```
public class LimitBook {
  private final TreeMap<Integer, Integer> bidTree = new TreeMap<>();
  private final TreeMap<Integer,Integer> askTree = new TreeMap<>();

  public void addToBidTree(Integer price, Integer size) {
    if (size == 0) {
      bidTree.remove(price);
    } else {
      bidTree.put(price,size);
    }
  }

  public void addToAskTree(Integer price, Integer size) {
    if (size == 0 ) {
      askTree.remove(price);
    } else {
      askTree.put(price,size);
    }
  }
  public Integer findByPrice(Integer price) {
    if (bidTree.containsKey(price)) {
      return bidTree.get(price);
    } else if (askTree.containsKey(price)) {
      return askTree.get(price);
    }
    return 0;
  }
  private Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> findBestAsk() {
    return askTree.firstEntry();
  }

  private Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> findBestBid() {
    return bidTree.lastEntry();

  }

  public String printBestBid() {
    Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> best = findBestBid();
    return best.getKey() + "," + best.getValue();
  }

  public String printBestAsk() {
    Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> best = findBestAsk();
    return best.getKey() + "," + best.getValue();
  }


  public void marketBuy(Integer size) {
    while(size > 0) {
      Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> best = askTree.firstEntry();
      if (best.getValue() > size) {
        askTree.put(best.getKey(),best.getValue()-size);
        size = 0;
      } else {
        size -= best.getValue();
        askTree.remove(best.getKey());
      }
    }
  }

  public void marketSell(Integer size) {
    while(size > 0) {
      Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> best = bidTree.lastEntry();
      if (best.getValue() > size) {
        bidTree.put(best.getKey(),best.getValue()-size);
        size = 0;
      } else {
        size -= best.getValue();
        bidTree.remove(best.getKey());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My main class :

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LimitBook book = new LimitBook();
        File file = new File("input.txt");

    try (LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file,"UTF-8");
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"))) {

      String[] query;
      String line;

      while (it.hasNext()) {
        line = it.nextLine().intern();
        query = line.split(",");

        switch (query[0]) {
          case "u" : {
            int price = Integer.parseInt(query[1]);
            int size = Integer.parseInt(query[2]);
            String type = query[3].intern();
            if (type.equals("bid")) {
              book.addToBidTree(price,size);
            } else {
              book.addToAskTree(price,size);
            }
            break;
          }
          case "o" : {
            String type = query[1].intern();
            int size = Integer.parseInt(query[2]);
            if (type.equals("buy")) {
              book.marketBuy(size);
            } else {
              book.marketSell(size);
            }
            break;
          }
          case "q" : {
            String type = query[1].intern();
            if (type.equals("best_bid")) {
              writer.write(book.printBestBid() + "\n");
            } else if (type.equals("best_ask")) {
              writer.write(book.printBestAsk() + "\n");
            } else {
              int price = Integer.parseInt(query[2]);
              writer.write(book.findByPrice(price) + "\n");
            }
            writer.flush();
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include your entire code, `import`s included

Comment: I removed the request you added to the question, as that's outside the scope of Code Review.  Either ask in comments to the question, or on [so] (after checking it's not already answered there - it probably is!).

Answer (score 2):

`findByPrice` in its current implementation uses double lookups; reduce these to single lookups knowing that `get` returns `null` on a missing key.

`findBestAsk` and `findBestBid` should be `public`, not `private`. The printing methods should not exist in that class. Even if they did, they should be called "format" and not "print" because they don't print.

`marketBuy` and `marketSell` are almost the same function. Make those two thin front-ends to a worker function.

The bulk of your code should not exist in `Main`. Write a parser class. There are many ways to further abstract this; the one I propose is somewhat modest in its abstraction and frames the new class as a combined parser, mutation dispatcher and iterator over output strings.

Do you really need a `BufferedWriter`? The bare `FileWriter` [does have buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899572/is-filewriter-buffered), and you should only opt to add a secondary write wrapper if you prove that your situation really needs it. Even funnier: you `.flush()`, negating the benefit of any buffering; don't do that.

`line.split(",")` can be replaced with a `Scanner`.

Make better use of `switch` instead of `if`/`else`. Do not apply a default `else` to the `sell` case; you should check for this explicitly and throw if the parsing fails to interpret the string.

Don't accept a boxed `Integer` type for `marketBuy` etc. parameters; accept `int` which is guaranteed non-null.

Your market trade loop can be simplified by subtracting from the size first and comparing to zero. The program output is the same but you are going to want to test thoroughly to make sure.

### Suggested

**Main.java**

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LimitBook book = new LimitBook();

        try (var writer = new FileWriter("output.csv", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
             var parser = new ActionParser("input.csv", book)) {

            for (String output: parser)
                writer.write(output);
        }
    }
}
```

**ActionParser.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ActionParser implements AutoCloseable, Iterable<String> {
    private final Scanner scanner;
    private final LimitBook book;

    public ActionParser(String filename, LimitBook book) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filename);
        this.book = book;
        scanner = new Scanner(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        scanner.useDelimiter("[,\r\n]");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        scanner.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return new ActionIterator();
    }

    private class ActionIterator implements Iterator<String> {
        private static String formatPair(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> pair) {
            return "%d,%d%n".formatted(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return scanner.hasNext();
        }

        private void update() {
            int price = scanner.nextInt();
            int size = scanner.nextInt();
            String type = scanner.next();
            switch (type) {
                case "bid" -> book.addToBidTree(price, size);
                case "ask" -> book.addToAskTree(price, size);
                default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }

        private void order() {
            String type = scanner.next();
            int size = scanner.nextInt();
            switch (type) {
                case "buy" -> book.marketBuy(size);
                case "sell" -> book.marketSell(size);
                default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }

        private String query() {
            String type = scanner.next();
            return switch (type) {
                case "best_bid" -> formatPair(book.findBestBid());
                case "best_ask" -> formatPair(book.findBestAsk());
                case "size" -> {
                    int price = scanner.nextInt();
                    yield "%d%n".formatted(book.findByPrice(price));
                }
                default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            };
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            String queryType = scanner.next();

            String output = switch (queryType) {
                case "u" -> { update(); yield ""; }
                case "o" -> { order(); yield ""; }
                case "q" -> query();
                default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            };

            if (scanner.hasNext()) scanner.nextLine();
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

**LimitBook.java**

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class LimitBook {
    private final TreeMap<Integer, Integer>
        bidTree = new TreeMap<>(),
        askTree = new TreeMap<>();

    public void addToBidTree(Integer price, Integer size) {
        if (size == 0)
            bidTree.remove(price);
        else bidTree.put(price, size);
    }

    public void addToAskTree(Integer price, Integer size) {
        if (size == 0)
            askTree.remove(price);
        else askTree.put(price, size);
    }

    public Integer findByPrice(Integer price) {
        Integer value = bidTree.get(price);
        if (value != null)
            return bidTree.get(price);

        value = askTree.get(price);
        if (value != null)
            return value;

        return 0;
    }

    public Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> findBestAsk() {
        return askTree.firstEntry();
    }

    public Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> findBestBid() {
        return bidTree.lastEntry();
    }

    public void marketBuy(int size) {
        marketTrade(size, askTree, TreeMap::firstEntry);
    }

    public void marketSell(int size) {
        marketTrade(size, bidTree, TreeMap::lastEntry);
    }

    private void marketTrade(
        int size,
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> tree,
        Function<TreeMap<Integer, Integer>, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> getBound
    ) {
        while (size > 0) {
            Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> best = getBound.apply(tree);
            size -= best.getValue();
            if (size < 0) {
                tree.put(best.getKey(), -size);
                break;
            }

            tree.remove(best.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code haven't passed performance testing and i get OutOfMemory.(limit is 128mb) You know where is the bottleneck?

Comment: You'll have to do some memory profiling. Nothing obvious springs to mind, unless `Scanner` is aggressively buffering the input

Comment: How to upgrade reading from File if we huge size of data?

Comment: It's likely that your trees are taking up most of the space, though you'll want to test this in runtime. If this is the case, then you have to critically examine your algorithm.

Comment: I have this problem with my solution and i solved it by adding intern() and flush inside a loop, and using LineIterator, but in this case it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   private final TreeMap<Integer, Integer> bidTree = new TreeMap<>();
>   private final TreeMap<Integer,Integer> askTree = new TreeMap<>();
> ```

In general, it is recommended that you code to the interface, not the implementation.  `TreeMap` is an implementation.  You probably want to code to `SortedMap`.

```
  private final SortedMap<Integer, Integer> bidTree = new TreeMap<>();
  private final SortedMap<Integer, Integer> askTree = new TreeMap<>();
```

Incidentally, I would not describe this as a binary search.  You binary search an array.  This is a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Trees) structure.  You could call it a Binary Search Tree (BST) if you want, but it doesn't do a binary search.  Most of the cleverness of a BST is in maintaining it.  Whereas a binary search array is simply a sorted array.  A binary search is just a method to search such a sorted array.

One wouldn't typically make a market work like this.  Instead of looking for the closest match, a typical market will produce either the lowest price (for a purchase) or the highest price (for a sale).  For those, the best data structure would be a `PriorityQueue`.  The heap used to implement a `PriorityQueue` will have lower overhead than a tree.  But you can still answer the essential question.  You cannot answer questions about a particular price, but you can still answer range questions by getting all of the results in sorted order and filtering out the ones that you don't want.

I.e. I don't think that `findByPrice` should be a requirement for a market.  And if it isn't, a `PriorityQueue` is a better match than a `TreeMap`.